# Vue.js eventBus doesn't emit property after page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to pass property from one component to other, they are siblings, after a page refresh. I want to do this on the page load.
I am using eventBus to do it:

```
EventBus.$emit('generatedSum', this.sum);
```

Receiving it in the sibling component with:

```
EventBus.$on('generatedSum', (sum) => {
      this.correct = sum;
    });
```

and I am puting both in the lifecycle hook:

```
created(){}
```

The problem is that after code is compiled after a saved change, I get the property emited to the sibling component, but when I manualy refresh the page the property is not visible in the sibling component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think when the page refreshes the Vue components mount one after another. Since both are siblings, when the first component `trigger the event` the second component may not be available to listen to the `triggered event`. Because the second component is mounted after the first component.

As a work around try
`mounted()` rather than using `created()` life cycle event.

More on life cycle events can be found here.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: It's an answer with facts. I just told him that it might not be the exact solution. And now there are no guesses  in the answer ;)

Comment: FWIW, yes, this is likely the issue. If you are not sure, its better to clarify with comments before answering.

Comment: @Bert Certainly ;)